# PHP include_once breaks site

Tags: php, include, include-path, php-include

I have to two include_once calls in my code:

```
include_once('../folder/folder/file.php');
include_once('../folder/folder/file2.php');
```

Its the correct file locations and was able to verily with `echo realpath()`

If I take one of them out, my code works minus what I need from the other file.

If I have both of them, I just get a blank screen, no error.

My question is, does php like two include_once starting with .. and how can I test which one is failing?

Comment: Use `__DIR__` constant and include absolute paths to your files. Also enable `error_reporting()` and set `display_errors` to true to see what's the error.

Comment: enable error display there is no reason for 2 include to break the site.

Comment: (1) multiple `include_once`'s are totally OK (2) read [How to get useful error messages in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: You obviously have some conflict between file.php and file2.php.

Comment: Something like the same named function defined in both is a likely possibility for a fatal error. Go look in your error log (which is what a blank screen means in PHP) then turn on `display_errors` as suggested. Easy at runtime with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` _Always do this_ when developing code.

Comment: Use `include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../folder/folder/file.php');`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is most likely that file one or file two read other files relevant to their directory. For example, if file one has code that says `fopen(file.txt)`, then you should change that to `fopen(../folder/folder/file.txt)`.

Make sure all statements in file one and file two that access other files use a path that is relative to the file that has the include_once statement.